# The equation $b^2=a(a^2-1)$ has no rational solutions except obvious ones

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I have problem with equation $b^2=a(a^2-1)$. How can I show that except $(a,b)=(1, 0), (-1,0),(0,0)$, the equation hasn't any other rational solutions ?

---

Editor's note. AFAICT the exercise is about showing that the rational points of the elliptic curve
$$y^2=x^3-x$$
are exactly the two-torsion points. This is probably known, but I am unfamiliar with this theory, so cannot point the OP to a resource, JL.

Comment: You could look at the residues mod 4 (or 8 maybe) and show that their patterns never coincide. The only solutions are therefore the trivial ones where b=0.

Comment: @user142299 But $a,b$ are rational numbers in general.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I misread the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The elliptic curve $b^2=a^3-a$ has a nontrivial rational solution iff $1$ is a congruent number. This is not the case, $1$ is not a congruent number. It is elementary to see that this would give a non-trivial integral solution to Fermat's equation $x^4+y^4=z^4$ (see exercise 3 in https://raw.github.com/williamstein/simuw12/master/day06/1.pdf‎).

Answer (score 1):

$$gcd(a,a^2-1)=1$$Which implies the only four combinations are
$$a=b^2 \land a^2-1=1 \lor a=1 \land a^2-1=b^2\\a=\sqrt2,b=\sqrt{\sqrt{2}} \lor a=1,b=0$$
And the negative solutions
$$a=-b^2\land a^2-1=-1 \lor a=-1 \land a^2-1=-b^2\\a=b=0 \lor a=-1,b=0$$

Comment: The question was not only for integral solutions, but for rational solutions.

Comment: Just saw it,gonna edit it when i think of the solution

Comment: @kingW3 Mate Hello, I am interested in your solution since I am looking for integral solutions.  Can you please tell how in 3rd line of your solution your wrote $ 1 \bigvee a = 1 \bigwedge a^2 -1 $?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi So there's 3 possibilities $a=1,a^2-1=b^2$ then $a=b^2,a^2-1=1$ and $a=b,a^2-1=b$ since $1,b,b^2$ are the only 3 divisors of $b^2$, but the last one isn't possible because $gcd(a,a^2-1)=1\neq gcd(b,b)=b$.

Comment: @kingW3  what does the symbol $\bigwedge $ means here? ie what does the equality $a = a\bigwedge a^2-1$ means ? Can you please tell?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi It means and, basically as enumerating solutions $a=b^2$ and $a^2-1=1$ must both be true for the equation to be satisfied

Comment: @kingW3 Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a rational solution exists, namely; $b=p/q$, and $a=r/s$ where $gcd(p,q)=1=gcd(r,s)$ otherwise cancel and start afresh. We have, $(p/q)^2=(r/s)[(r/s)^2-1]$ so that 
$p^2=q^2*r(r^2-s^2)/s^3$, from here we must have at least $s^3|q^2$ similarly, we can show that $q^2|s^3$, so that $q^2=s^3$, now there are two cases; either $q=s$ [in which case we have $q^2=q^3$ or $q=s=1$, so that we are confined to integers whose solutions are the trivial cases provided above] or $gcd(q,s)=k$, so let $q=kq'$ and $s=ks'$, where $gcd(q',s')=1$ then, $k^2*q'^2=k^3*s'^3$ or $q'^2/s'^3=k$, which is impossible since $gcd(q',s')=1$, hence no solution exist.

Comment: The last equation doesn't lead to a contradiction.  In fact, given that $q^2 = s^3$, it follows that $q = r^3$ and $s = r^2$ for some integer $r$.  Then we have $k = s$, $q' = r$, and $s' = 1$, so the final equation simply says that $q'^2/s'^3 = r^2/1^3 = r^2$.  In any case, this type of approach shouldn't lead to a correct proof, because it would apply equally well to other elliptic curves, including those with infinitely many non-integral rational points.